# Text based watermark?

Tags: java, html, css, glassfish, watermark

I'm looking to do a text based watermark that only shows up in the dev/test version of our GlassFish run site.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486786/1174838 does mostly what I want.  The only problem is that the text watermark is obscuring some buttons.  How do I make the watermark behind everything but still be visible?

Comment: How about a background image.

Answer (score 0):

give a try with `z-index`, in assumption you are placing the watermark with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mixture of:

```
z-index:/\*some high value\*/;
```

&

```
user-select:none;
```

And also use relative / absolute positioning to get the watermark into the right location, ex.:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
```

*( Note that user-select:none; needs vendor prefixes at this point in time )*